# How to sell a dynamically generated file?

Tags: php, paypal

I sell a (very cheap and dynamically generated through PHP) file of data online. For the payment, I use a basic PayPal button.

This has two advantages I want to keep:

- PayPal is known, and people are not afraid to proceed to payment, as they are on PayPal website when they pay (they get redirected to my website at the end of the process, and the file automatically downloads).
- I don't need any SSL certificate on my website (quite expensive).

This has several drawbacks, I would like to be fixing:

- As the file is dynamically generated in PHP, I would like to be choosing the price and the currency dynamically (according to many parameters; currently the price is fixed).
- In my JavaScript, there is POST action, with a hidden "return" parameter (the URL customer get redirected to once payment is successful). If you know this URL, you can get the file without paying. This is a big security flaw here in my implementation (even if most of my users won't know how to inspect client code)

I understand I should be using the PHP PayPal API rather than the basic PayPal button. The workflow I imagine is:

- a PayPal button on the page when clicked, triggers a server side PHP script.
- this PHP script decides of the price, contacts PayPal with the return URL (not available on client side) and redirects the client to this payment page on PayPal.
- the client pays in PayPal secure environment and, once payment is successful, gets redirected to my website with a temporary authenticated token (?) so he cannot transfer this URL to someone else and the file download happens.

I am a little lost with the PayPal documentation. Could you confirm my architecture principles and provides me some sample PHP codes in order to achieve all that?

Other questions: I currently have a basic PayPal account. Do I need I business account? Do I need an SSL certificate? Do you know good alternatives to PayPal to do all that? Google? Visa?

Comment: Way too broad, way too many individual questions, and way too many asking for opinions. We're not here to critique your plans, your designs, or help you choose hosting/payment systems.

Comment: Obviously, you'd better close that security-hole, if only to discover how many people have already discovered it, too. **:-O**  Beyond this, "you're a *businessman,* and it really is up to you to decide how to price and sell your product to your customers." Categorically, I suggest keeping things very simple: don't present the customer with a lot of decisions because, if they decide they made the wrong one, they're gonna start pestering PayPal for adjustments (and, getting them, as any customer would do). Don't sell three alternatives when one will do. Good-will is better than another dollar.